# The graph of the web: the dataset of links between web pages

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, internet

I was looking for the dataset of links between web pages and found these options:

- [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/get-started/): Public web crawling data. It includes "the HTTP headers returned and the *links (including the type of link) listed on the page*." AFAIK, it's the most comprehensive and up-to-date source.
- [SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html): Small samples of the web graph (up to 7M edges). Including [Google's version](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Google.html).

Are you aware about other sources of the similar data? Preferably comprehensive, with big coverage, rather than frequent updates.

Comment: Is there anything unusable with the sources you link to, or are you just looking for a bigger list?